# for loop number sequence of (1,1,2,2,3,3, etc.)

Tags: javascript, loops, math, for-loop

I looked it up and this pattern is [Hofstadter Female sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Female_and_Male_sequences). The equations are:

**M(n) = n-F(M(n-1))**

**F(n) = n-M(F(n-1))**

but I'm not sure how to put that into code.

So far I have:

```
while () {
    _p++
    _r++
    if (_p % 2 === 0) {
        _r = _p - 1;
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: What programming language? And what have you tried writing so far?

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `while` loop.

Comment: Any scripting language really. I'm happen to be doing this in javascript

Comment: I've posted what I have so far

Comment: what does OOP have to do with the price of tea in china or this question?

Comment: I assumed that this question as about how to calculate the price of tea futures in China :P

Comment: @Zhafur JavaScript is heavily object-based. Objects are associative arrays, augmented with prototypes (see below). Object property names are associative array keys: obj.x = 10 and obj["x"] = 10 are equivalent, the dot notation being merely syntactic sugar. Properties and their values can be added, changed, or deleted at run-time. The properties of an object can also be enumerated via a for...in loop.

Comment: I stated before "Any OOP scripting language really" and instead of getting any help, someone just tells me javascript isn't an OOP language. Then I edited because I felt dumb. I read more about it, and found that everything will be ok in this world.

But seriously... any tips here?

Comment: Guys, would you discuss your opinions about OOP somewhere else? I has nothing to to with this complex algorithmic question here.

Comment: @Tom: What do you expect your code to output? Give it a number, and compute a sequence of that length? Produce the nth number?

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to spit out a sequence of 1,1,2,2,3,3 and so on. It seems really easy, I've drank way too much coffee, and I think I'm overcomplicating it.

Comment: @Zhafur: By most reasonable definitions (i.e. ones that are generous enough to include C++), JavaScript is definitely an OO language. It has objects up the wazoo.

Comment: @Tom If all you asked for was the sequence 1,1,2,2,3,3,... then this would have been my answer: `for( var i=2 ; i<=10 ; ++i ) console.log(i>>1)`. In contrast, Hofstadter's Female sequence starts out this way, but only has one 4, for instance.

Comment: @Tom: spit out how, `console.log`? So on till when, forever?

Comment: @matt a sign-propagating right shift operator is exactly what I needed. First time I've ever used it. Thank you so much. I'm so embarrassed that I should delete this whole thread...

Comment: @Tom What? No, don't delete this thread; I'm a big fan of Hofstadter and [*Gödel, Escher, Bach*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach). Let's keep this here for anyone in the future searching for these recurrence relations :)

Comment: @Matt I might have to read that one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

```
function F(n)
{
    return 0 < n ? n - M(F(n-1)) : 1
}

function M(n)
{
    return 0 < n ? n - F(M(n-1)) : 0
}

var N = 10;
var f = [];
var m = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
    f.push(F(i));
    m.push(M(i));
}

console.log('F: ' + f.join(','))
console.log('M: ' + m.join(','))
```

Output:

```
F: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6
M: 0,0,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KtGBg/1/

Comment: I'm curious but is it only possible to do this with this equation and two functions?

Comment: Yes the equations reference each other in the original definition

Answer (score 3):

Recursion should be avoided, if possible, so you can cache the already-calculated values for **F(n)** and **M(n)** :

```
var f = new Array();
var m = new Array();

function F(n){
    if(f[n] != undefined) {
        return f[n];
    }
    if (n==0) { 
       value = 1;
    } else {
       value = n - M(F(n-1));
    }
    f[n] = value;
    return value;
}

function M(n){
    if(m[n] != undefined) {
        return m[n];
    }
    if (n==0) { 
       value = 0;
    } else {
       value = n - F(M(n-1));
    }
    m[n] = value;
    return value;
}
```

This yields a much faster result for greater numbers (try it with 10000)

Comment: Wait I'm confused, how does your approach avoid recursion?

Comment: It's not avoiding completely, it is just caching the results for **F(0)**, **F(1)**,  ... **F(9999)** etc. So, we don't enter the recursion if we have the result. Imagine how many times you would have to calculate **F(0)** otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
function F(n){
    if (n==0) return 1
    else return n - M(F(n-1))
}

function M(n){
    if (n==0) return 0
    else return n - F(M(n-1))
}

var str = ""
for(var i=0; i<=10; i++) str += F(i) + ", "
console.log(str.substr(0,str.length-2))
```

Comment: That string building is ugly. Use `for (var arr=[]; arr.length<=10; ) arr.push(F(arr.length)); console.log(arr.join(", "))`

Comment: @Bergi I see nothing wrong with this particular string building activity.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [GaborSch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21611282/95592), you could use [Doug Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com) `memoizer` function, which can be found in Chapter 4 of *[Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742).* Using memoization took the calculation time for the first 150 terms of the male and female Hofstadter sequences down to 256 ms as compared to almost 8 seconds without memoization.

```
var memoizer = function (memo, formula) {
  var recur = function (n) {
    var result = memo[n];
    if (typeof result !== 'number') {
      result = formula(recur, n);
      memo[n] = result;
    }
    return result;
  };
  return recur;
};

var maleHofstadter = memoizer([0], function (recur, n) {
  return n - femaleHofstadter(recur(n-1));
});

var femaleHofstadter = memoizer([1], function (recur, n) {
  return n - maleHofstadter(recur(n-1));
});

var N = 150;
var f = [];
var m = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
  f.push(femaleHofstadter(i));
  m.push(maleHofstadter(i));
}

console.log('F: ' + f.join(','));
console.log('M: ' + m.join(','));
```

Comment: A generic `memoizer` and clean Hofstadter implementation.  Beautiful :)

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for measuring the difference between memoized and direct recursion. +1 from me :)